# Fast way to count and remove duplicates from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, duplicates

I have an array that contains duplicates

```
array = ["String 1", "string 2", "STRING 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 1"]
```

I want to get get rid of duplicates (case insensitive) and create a new array that counts the duplicates.

In one of the answers, I saw this function:

```
function count_array(arr) {
    var a = [], b = [], prev;

    arr.sort();
    for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        if ( arr[i] !== prev ) {
             a.push(arr[i]);
             b.push(1);
        } else {
             b[b.length-1]++;
        }
        prev = arr[i];
     }
     return [a, b];
 }
```

which returns two arrays:

```
First array: ["String 1", "String 2", "STRING 1", "String 3"]
Second array: [2, 2, 1, 1]
```

It it not case insensitive, I want all instance of `String 1, STRING 1, string 1, StRING 1` to be considered as `String 1`.

Also is there a better way to do this for large arrays? for example an array length of 10K?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reduce the array of strings to an object, using the strings as keys, and the number of appearances as values. Use `Object.keys()` to get the first array, and `Object.values()` for second:

```js
const array = ["String 1", "string 2", "STRING 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 1"]

const counts = array.reduce((r, s) => {
  const key = s[0].toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
  
  r[key] = (r[key] || 0) + 1;
  
  return r;
}, {});

const first = Object.keys(counts);
const second = Object.values(counts);

console.log(first);
console.log(second);
```

To get the result sorted by the number of duplicates, use `Object.entries()` to convert the results of the reduce to an array of pairs. Sort by the 2nd value (the counts). To get the two array, use `Array.map()`.

```js
const array = ["String 1", "string 2", "STRING 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 1"]

const counts = Object.entries(array.reduce((r, s) => {
  const key = s[0].toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
  
  r[key] = (r[key] || 0) + 1;
  
  return r;
}, {}))
.sort(([, a], [, b]) => b - a);

const first = counts.map(([s]) => s);
const second = counts.map(([, n]) => n);

console.log(first);
console.log(second);
```

Comment: I think `Object.keys` is `O(n)` so I am not sure about the performance on large arrays?

Comment: Since you need an array of `n` items - `O(n)` is pretty good.

Comment: thank you, in your answer, is it possible to order from highest number of duplicate counts to lowest?

Comment: See updates. Note - the complexity of `Array.sort()` is `O(n log(n))`

Answer (score 2):

`.sort()` is an `O(N log N)` process - if you *need* to sort the results, do it at the very end, if speed is something you're worried about. If you *don't* need to sort the results, then use a `Set` (or a `Map`) instead to check for duplicates, instead of checking a sorted array for similar items in adjacent indicies.

```js
array = ["String 1", "string 2", "STRING 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 1"]
function count_array(arr) {
  const result = [];
  const map = new Map();
  arr.forEach((str) => {
    const lower = str.toLowerCase();
    const currCount = map.get(lower) || 0;
    if (!currCount) {
      result.push(str);
    }
    map.set(lower, currCount + 1);
  });
  console.log([...map.values()]);
  return result.sort();
}
console.log(count_array(array));
```

You can use a `for` loop instead of `forEach` if you want, a `for` loop will be slightly faster, though a bit harder to read IMO:

```js
array = ["String 1", "string 2", "STRING 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 1"]
function count_array(arr) {
  const result = [];
  const map = new Map();
  for (let i = 0, { length } = arr; i < length; i++) {
    const str = arr[i];
    const lower = str.toLowerCase();
    const currCount = map.get(lower) || 0;
    if (!currCount) {
      result.push(str);
    }
    map.set(lower, currCount + 1);
  }
  console.log([...map.values()]);
  return result.sort();
}
console.log(count_array(array));
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation, your answer does not count the items? I want to get a second array which corresponds to the number of duplicates from array 1

Comment: Oh, you wanted the counts as well, use a `Map` instead of a set to keep track

Comment: Is it possible to get them in two separate arrays? I am using the return arrays in another function that accepts two different arrays

Comment: Just take the second item from each array in the map to get the counts that correspond to each string.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a some functions and filter noramlized values with counting them.

```js
const
    normalize = s => s.toLowerCase(),
    getFirst = a => a,
    mapCount = (m, k) => m.set(k, (m.get(k) || 0) + 1),
    array = ["String 1", "string 2", "STRING 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 1"],
    map = new Map,
    array1 = array.filter(v => (k => getFirst(!map.has(k), mapCount(map, k)))(normalize(v))),
    array2 = Array.from(map.values());

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```

If you are satified with normalized strings as result set, you could take this approach.

```js
const
    normalize = s => s.toLowerCase(),
    mapCount = (m, k) => m.set(k, (m.get(k) || 0) + 1),
    array = ["String 1", "string 2", "STRING 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 1"],
    map = array.reduce((m, v) => mapCount(m, normalize(v)), new Map),
    array1 = Array.from(map.keys()),
    array2 = Array.from(map.values());

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the fastest way to do this it should be done in `Big-O(N)` asymptotically:

1. Firstly, you need a hash map to store all your past strings;
2. Secondly, you need to iterate over your given array placing its values into the hash map;
3. Finally, you need to increment count of the string in the hash map every time it is met.

It can be implemented like so:

```
const arr = [...];
const map = {};

for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {
    const str = arr[i].toLowerCase();

    if (str in map) {
        map[str]++;

        // keep in mind that removing element from an array costs O(N)
        arr[i] = undefined;
    } else {
        map[str] = 1;
    }
}

// now you have the hash map that represents all strings and its numbers of appearances in the given array
doSomething(map);

// finally return filtered result
return arr.filter(str => str !== undefined);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done succinctly using `Array.reduce` to create a map whose keys are the lowercased items of your array and the values are their count. Then get the unique items using `Object.keys()` and get the counts with `Object.values()`:

```js
const array = ["String 1", "string 2", "STRING 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 1"];

const map = array.reduce((acc, x) => {
  const xLower = x.toLocaleLowerCase();
  acc[xLower] = (acc[xLower] || 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(map);
console.log(Object.keys(map));
console.log(Object.values(map));
```